# Hover and Click image to reveal content (With initial content displayed)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to get the following to work:

- When initially loaded, content on the right for the initial image is displayed (and should be coloured).
- On hover over the images, the images will change to colour and the content for that image will appear on the right hand side.
- On Click the content will stay in the right hand side and the image will stay coloured as it is the selected content.

I understand you could just make the images simply have a rollover feature using CSS for the coloured images to appear, however I am unaware how to make the image stay coloured when clicked and how to make the content in the right appear, which I assume would be possible to do using Jquery or Javascript.

What it looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/73oFL.png

```
<ul id="testb">
    <li id="companies">
        <img src="images/linkedin.gif" width="120" height="95" alt="" />
        <img src="images/specsavers.gif" width="100" height="95" alt="" />
        <img src="images/avc.gif" width="110" height="95" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li id="testcont">content here</li></ul>
```

```
#testb{
width:950px;
margin:0 auto;
list-style:none;
padding:0;
}
#companies{
    width:440px;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    padding:85px 0 45px 0;
    margin:0;
    height:130px;
    display:block;
}
#testcont{
    float:left;
    width:395px;
    height:170px;
    padding:45px 0 45px 70px;
    margin:0;
    background: url(images/testglow.gif) no-repeat;
}
```

If you could help out it would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please display your attempt(s) of doing this. I don't see **any** hover state in your css or javascript events/functions so it's unclear what the problem is. If you expect people to just make your wish list happen then you're at the wrong place. Stack Overflow is for developers to debug source code, find the problem(s), explain the problem(s) and offer a solution if possible, **not** a site for people to post requests and expect free source code.

Answer (score 0):

Even tho NewToJS is **absolutely right**, sometimes a little free source code might help you get started:

```js
var contentValues = ["slide 1 content", "slide 2 content", "slide 3 content"];
var contentColors = ["#333333", "#777777", "#000000"];
$(function() {
    $("#companies img").on("mouseover", function()
    {
      console.log($(this).data("slide"));
      $("#testcont").html(contentValues[$(this).data("slide")]);
      $("#testcont").css("background-color",contentColors[$(this).data("slide")]);
      
    });

    $("#companies img").on("click", function()
    {
      console.log($(this).data("slide"));
      
      $("#companies img").css("background-color", "transparent")
      
      $(this).css("background-color", contentColors[$(this).data("slide")]);
      
    });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="testb">
    <li id="companies">
        <img data-slide="0" src="images/linkedin.gif" width="120" height="95" alt="" />
        <img data-slide="1" src="images/specsavers.gif" width="100" height="95" alt="" />
        <img data-slide="2" src="images/avc.gif" width="110" height="95" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li id="testcont">content here</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I didn't intend on being rude and just expecting the code to be delivered for me, more a pointer in the right direction! I forgot to mention this, as quite simply I have no idea about any Javascript at all and haven't done nearly any coding in around 6 years now.

I have tried what you have suggested, however I don't seem to understand why it's not working for me in my document - yet it is on the code snippet provided and when I integrate my code using jsfiddle.

Comment: No problem man!  sometimes a little code is great to start moving around. Did you include jquery? this should also be wrapped in a $(function() {

}); Check out the edit i just did

Comment: I edited my comment and you had already commented by time I edited, so not sure if you will have read the rest of my message to potentially help me out a little bit more!

https://jsfiddle.net/xowkc9fg/ - on the jsfiddle it works perfectly, however when I put it into the html document it doesn't work? When hovering or clicking on the image, nothing changes.